# Pivoting a large table

Tags: sql, postgresql, matrix, binary, pivot

I have a very messy table with two kinds of columns, a 'start' point and a 'end' point. Wherever the start point occurs, there is a `1`, and wherever the end point occurs, there is a `1`. All other cells are filled with zeros, so each row only contains two `1` values. Here's a general idea of what it looks like:

```
 datetime       id     start_a start_b start_c .... start_z  end_a ....... end_z
 2018-01-01    900141    1        0      0     ....    0       0   .......   1
 2018-01-02    900142    0        1      0     ....    0       1   .......   0
 2018-01-02    901143    0        0      1     ....    0       0   .......   1    
   .             .       .        .      .     ....    .       .   .......   .
   .             .       .        .      .     ....    .       .   .......   .
   .             .       .        .      .     ....    .       .   .......   .
```

There are a large number of columns in this data due to various starting points and endpoints. Moreover, there are a large number of dates as well. What I want to do is convert this table into the following format:

```
datetime        id     start    end
2018-01-01    900141     a       z
2018-01-02    900142     b       a
2018-01-02    901143     c       z
    .            .       .       .
    .            .       .       .
    .            .       .       .
    .            .       .       .
```

This seems very difficult to do. I've heard `crosstab()` queries are a potential solution, but how would this be possible given the number of columns I have? Anytips on how to go about pivoting my massive messy table?